# How do I sample all threads and record their thread id with perf?

Tags: perf

I want to get information about what each thread is doing at regular intervals. Unfortunately I can see in the `perf script` output that no thread id is recorded, because the output looks the same with `-F +tid` as with `-F -tid`.

I tried using the `--per-thread` option but it doesn't do what I want. Instead, it seems to drop the timestamp field from the data.

Is this possible? If not, what does the data reported by `perf` for a multithreaded program mean – does it just sample the main thread, or random threads?

Comment: Normally `perf stat -I 1000 ./some_program` accumulates results from *all* threads in each 1000ms interval.

Comment: I should clarify that I'm interested in perf record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, `perf record` already records threads and their ID. What got me confused is that the thread ID of the main thread is equal to the process ID. I also must have been doing something wrong when doing the `-F -tid` test, because indeed the column with the thread ID disappears.